# Page number for references with pdf_book is final reference page, not first

Tags: r, reference, bookdown, tableofcontents, bibliography

In the file _output.yml, I have

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  toc_depth: 2
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  toc_bib: true
  keep_tex: yes
```

The toc page numbers are all correct, except for the page number
for what I have called References rather than Bibliography,
which is 84 where it should be 81.

(I used

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
```

in index.Rmd to change the name to References, but have
checked that this make no difference to the number in the toc)

Added August 19 2021:
It turns out that if I go back and rerun "Build Book" after running it with citation_package: natbib removed, then rerun with citation_package: natbib added back in again, the references appear
thus (. . . for references after the first), and the page number in the table of contents is correct.

```
\begin{CSLReferences}{0}{0}
\leavevmode\hypertarget{ref-r2_begley_2013}{}%
Begley, C. G. 2013. {``Reproducibility: Six Red Flags for Suspect Work.''} \emph{Nature} 497 (7450): 433--34. \url{https://doi.org/10.1038/497433a}.
. . .
\end{CSLReferences}
```

and the page reference is correct.

Comment: What does the generated LaTeX look like at the start of the References section?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the pagination is correct if I remove `citation_package: natbib` from `_output.yaml`, under `bookdown::pdf_book:`.  The citations are not in all respects handled correctly (at least in version 0.22 of bookdown), unless one uses Pandoc's default for handling citations.